# how to mention OR in json object . Unable to query using two vales in json

Tags: json, mongodb

I am trying to query from mongo DB using a json object .

I need to return all the objects that have status both as "in production" and "in progress" . I need to send it in a json format .

```
{status: "In Progress"}
```

however i need all the values that have status both "In progress" and "In Production "

so How do i mention Or in json ?

```
{status: ["In Progress","In Production"]}
```

I tried doing it like this but it doesnt seem to work.

Also i was trying to query from mongo

```
{ status : { $or: [ {"In Production"} ,{"In Progress"} ] }  }
```

This also gives some error saying expected ":"

Answer (score 1):

You have the `in` operator:

```
{ status: $in: ["In Progress","In Production"] }
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/